Getting body from hpack http2 request nodejs
I am making request with http2 and hpack. So it's in node js and what I want to do is to get body of page that I'm sending request to. But I only could get its payload of headers. Here is how does it looks like:
This is how does the payload look like
 [ ':status', '200' ] and etc, stack is not giving me to paste it all.
There is my code (not the full one, also because the stack is not giving me to print everything):
const net = require('net');
const tls = require('tls');
const HPACK = require('hpack');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

tlsSocket.on('data', (eventData) => {
    data = Buffer.concat([data, eventData])

    while (data.length >= 9) {
        const frame = decodeFrame(data)
        if (frame != null) {
            data = data.subarray(frame.length + 9)

            if (frame.type == 1) {
                console.log("PAYLOAD:")
                console.log(hpack.decode(frame.payload))
                console.log("BODY:") // BODY
                console.log(hpack.decode(frame.body)) // BODY PRINT

                const title = "FIND TITLE"; // FIND TITLE IN BODY
                
                console.log(title)
            }
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
})

So, frame.body doesn't exist in reality, so can I use to get the body?
So, I want it to print the body + to get the title of the website and print it in console.
